# How to control ui resizable to minheight?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to control ui resizable to minimum height setup. I cannot control by its handler. 
https://jsfiddle.net/winstonchang/dfqtt/

```
    $('#resize').resizable({
helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
  grid: [10, 10]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add **minWidth: 150,** or **minHeight: 150**

```
$('#resize').resizable({
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
    minWidth: 150,
    minHeight: 150,
    grid: [10, 10]
});
```